# Alternating black and white material for text characters

Tags: shader-nodes

I am trying to add a alternating black and white material to the face of the text. The text has to stay editable and can not be made a mesh. I would like it to alternate from back and white on each character randomly at first and slowly end up with all of them being white.

I have used the wave texture node and the invert node which kind of of works but each character is not totally white or black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That would be hard to do in the node editor without some typesetting constraints.  Either each letter should be the same width or spaced differently and then some math should be able to handle it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 5):

If rendering in Cycles, with simple, flat text, this is relatively easy to do.  You can use a geometry/random from island as a lookup on a noise texture:

[image]

Here, I'm combining a random-per-island with a value node driven by #frame.  If I'd like to bias this over time to some particular value, I can keyframe the "greater than" threshold.  If that threshold is 0, all letters will be white.  If it is 1, all letters will be black.

I've also shown here why the letters need to be flat for this to work.  Once we use extrusion (or bevel) on our letters, they have geometry with new islands, leading to different random values.  Note that even with flat letters, the dot of an i, for example, would be a different island, and thus potentially a different color, from the rest of the i.

If we need this to work in Eevee, or with text with geometry, it's not so hard; we just have to turn it into an actual mesh object so that we can weld vertices and UV map it, then use any of a number of techniques to get a unique identifier for each letter:

[image]

We'll start by using "convert to" operation to convert the text to a mesh object.  Then we'll enter edit on it and merge all vertices by distance (distance 0).  Then we'll UV map it, with a simple project from view.  Finally, here, I select all UV coordinates and scale, about individual origins, to 0.  Now, each letter has a constant, unique UV coordinate that I can use to create letter-wide random numbers.

Consider the "i" problem mentioned above.  Doing what i just mentioned will give us a different color for the dot of the i and the rest of it.  But if we want these to have the same color, all we need to do is give them the same UV coordinate.  We can select the UV coordinates for the whole i and scale to 0 in median, instead of individual origins, to give it that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is possible to do with shader nodes alone. But this is as close as I could get.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it!

Comment: This makes some letters highlighted partially https://i.imgur.com/Hgjnj4i.png